# Django : Get date wise count in Datetimefield

Tags: python, mysql, django, date

I have a class which has datetimefield

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='status_id')
    date_field = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    f1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    f2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I want to apply filter on date in DateTimeField and get the output in following format after doing some query:

**f2 date_field f1**
 54 2017-02-01 4 
 53 2017-02-01 6 
 52 2017-02-01 2 
 51 2017-02-01 1 
 48 2017-02-01 5 
 47 2017-02-01 2 
 46 2017-02-01 3 
 45 2017-02-01 2 
 41 2017-02-01 1 
 38 2017-02-01 3 
 32 2017-02-01 17 
 30 2017-02-01 3 
 29 2017-02-01 4 
 18 2017-02-01 4 
 14 2017-02-01 5 
 13 2017-02-01 2

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:-

```
from django.db.models import Count 
Foo.objects.values('f2','date_field','f1').annotate(dcount=Count('date_field')
```

Comment: my date field is datetimefield and i want filters on the basis date not datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question quite unclear. However, from your example I see the list is ordered on your `f2` field. To filter on your `order_by('field')`. To filter a field, you can use `.filter()` on your `queryset`. To filter on, for example today, we can pass the `datetime.now()` from the `datetime` library. To format your date, you can use `date/dateTime-object.strftime('<format>')`. But please, clarify your question, your actual question is quite a guess for us.

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
foos = Foo.objects.filter(date_field=today) \ 
        .order_by('-f2') \
        .annotate(date_count=Count('date_field'))

for foo in foos:
    date_formatted = foo.date_field.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print foo.f2, date_formatted, foo.date_count
```